# Is it legit to put a condition under a limit like $\lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (0,0) \\ y=0 }} \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

**Question**: I kinda forgot my multivariable limits already...

Is it legit to put a condition under a limit eg $\lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (0,0) }} \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ doesn't exist because

$$\lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (0,0) \\ y=0 }} \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$

$$= \lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (0,0) \\ y=0 }} \frac{x}{x^2}$$

$$= \lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (0,0)}} \frac{x}{x^2}$$

$$= \lim_{\substack{x \to 0}} \frac{x}{x^2}$$

$$= \lim_{\substack{x \to 0}} \frac{1}{x}$$

doesn't exist

?

---

**Explanation**: The thing is in single variable real: it's legit to say $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac 1 x$ because there's a precise definition for this where instead of $- \delta < x - 0 < \delta$ you say $0 < x - 0 < \delta$ or something. Hence, here it's legit to write $\lim_{\substack{x \to 0 \\ x > 0}} \frac 1 x := \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac 1 x$.

I would like to know this is similarly legit in complex/real multivariable, if it is. I think if this isn't legit, then I would like to know the proper way to argue. Perhaps say $\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{1}{x}$ for $y=0$ and thus... (wait let's change to $x=0$) let's say $\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} = 0$ for $x=0$ and thus $\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \to 0$ as $y \to 0$ along $x=0$...but I don't know how to make this precise either.

---

(Context: I'm actually asking with complex limits in mind, but I guess it will be [equivalent to real multivariable limits anyway](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268942/what-exactly-are-the-differences-between-real-multivariable-limits-and-complex-l).)

---

**Guess**:

Ah wait writing all this I think I figured it out.

(convert to answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a notation hasn't been defined, it's technically not legit to use it.

On the other hand, some extensions of notations have so obvious meaning that they hardly need an explicit definition. [IMHO](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IMHO) your notation belongs to this class. Therefore I consider it legit.

Comment: 'If a notation hasn't been defined, it's technically not legit to use it.' --> God bless you, md2perpe. thank you.

Comment: ok but basically adding a condition under a limit is just adding a condition on the $z$ or $(x,y)$ or $x$ on top of the $0 < |\cdot|< \delta$ thing as described in [my guess answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269433/is-it-legit-to-put-a-condition-under-a-limit-like-lim-substackx-y-to-0/4269459#4269459)?

Comment: The obvious interpretation of $\lim_{\substack{x\to a \\ P(x) }} f(x) = L$ is 
$$\forall \epsilon>0 \, \exists \delta>0 \,\forall x : (|x-a|<\delta \land P(x) \implies |f(x)-L| < \epsilon).$$

Comment: md2perpe ok...thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Guess**:

The generalisation of changing $-\delta < x - 0 < \delta$ to $0 < x - 0 < \delta$ is that we take the intersection of $- \delta < x - 0 < \delta$ with $x > 0$. Therefore,

the original definition of

$$\lim_{\substack{x \to a}} f(x) = L$$

as

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 \ \text{s.t.} \  |f(x)-L| < \varepsilon \ \text{whenever} \ 0<|x-a|<\delta \ (\text{and} \ x \in Domain(f))$$

extends to

$$\lim_{\substack{x \to a \\ \text{condition on x}}} f(x) = L$$ defined as

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 \ \text{s.t.} \  |f(x)-L| < \varepsilon \ \text{whenever}$$

$$\ 0<|x-a|<\delta \ (\text{and} \ x \in Domain(f)) \ \text{and} \ \text{condition on x}$$

Therefore in multivariable or even complex the legit-ness (legitimacy) of conditions is like...

$$\lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (0,0) \\ x=0 }} \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$ defined as

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 \ \text{s.t.} \  |\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}-0| < \varepsilon \ \text{whenever}$$

$$\ 0<\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2}<\delta \ (\text{and} \ (x,y) \in Domain(f)) \ \text{and} \ \{x=0\}$$

(where $f: Domain(f) \to \mathbb R, f(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$)

---

**Edit**: To further increase legitimacy:

$$\text{condition on x}$$

is merely a fancy way of saying

$$x \in A$$

for some subset $A \subseteq \mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R^2$